# Open file in Windows instead of Chrome

Tags: file, hyperlink, geojson

I just know how to link to the local file from browser, regarding to the queries here:

[How to open local file from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430889/how-to-open-local-file-from-browser/46431022)

[How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)

[html link to local file and open in local application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835836/html-link-to-local-file-and-open-in-local-application)

```
 <a href='file:///Z:\\Fixed Line\\Design & Build\\2. Clients\\Openreach\\3. MDU Designs\\Coventry\\OR66 - Priory Court, Coventry\\
```

this code works when I want to open the local file in the browser.

I tried to put another code regarding to 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

```
 <a href='file://///Z:\\Fixed Line\\Design & Build\\2. Clients\\Openreach\\3. MDU Designs\\Coventry\\OR66 - Priory Court, Coventry\\
```

But it still open in the browser.

I want to have it opened in Windows (or another local application) instead the Chrome (or another browser).

Is it possible? What should I do to get this result?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a partial solution can be using IE instead of Chrome or Opera.

The IE open the local directory path directly via Windows (or other local HDD app), unlike to other web browsers, keeping this path visible in their tabs only.

[image]